Newton's Cooling Law: "Small difference in temperature"
I'm reading about Newton's Cooling Law, and it is mentioned that it only works for "small temperature differences." My question, is how small is that difference for conduction? I'm doing a school project on this, and I'm wondering if it is a set value, or something like a proportion of the object's temperature. Also, if someone could share with me a source where it says what this "small difference" is, I'd appreciate it!

By "small temperature differences" it means that thermal conductivity coefficient of the material should not depend on material temperature. This is usually true when $\Delta T$ is small, but how exactly small it should be,- depends on exact material, because they vary in thermal conductivity properties.

Newton's law of cooling says that the flux scales linearly with the temperature difference—that is, that the flux for a certain temperature difference is modulated by a constant convection coefficient, or a constant thermal conductivity.
All linear relations are approximate. Convection coefficients vary with temperature, so if you're considering a given temperature, you're making an approximation by using a single value. Thermal conductivities also vary with temperature, so the same caveat applies. Heat transfer also encompasses radiation, for example, which is nonlinear in relation to a temperature difference. And that's just the standard heat transfer treatment; it's not clear what system you're analyzing.
So if you're going to present an analysis based on Newton's law of cooling, the onus is on you to demonstrate that the convection coefficient and/or the thermal conductivity can be reasonably assumed to be essentially constant over the temperature range you're considering, and that any substantial radiative heat transfer can also be linearized to scale approximately linearly over that range. In practice, that means looking up the appropriate material properties and evaluating the relevant heat transfer mechanisms and demonstrating that the use of a single coefficient produces a reasonably accurate prediction.
In other words, there is no set value. If you can accept a 5% error, for example, then you have to demonstrate that the phenomena and material properties vary by less than an amount that would reasonably produce that 5% error.
